# Bad Access when trying to access a Mutable Array with an NSMutableString

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablestring

I synthesized an `NSMutableArray` called email, which is part of an object Person. The email array contains pointers to several `NSMutableString` objects.

```
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *email;
@synthesize email = _email;
```

The string was declared (in the init method of the email object) as follows:

```
NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Blah"];
```

With this, I get a bad access error when I later executed an `[email count]` command in a different method. I use automatic retain counting ARC. Why does this happen?

EDIT: It turned out to be important that the output of `[email count]` was printed using %@, which won't work most of the time, see below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out, I think.

Makes it glaringly obvious how green I am with Cocoa / Objective C. I was printing a test message as follows:

`NSLog (@"%@",[[p email] count]);`

But the count method returns an unsigned long (or NSInteger), and as soon as I changed it into

`NSLog (@"%ul",....`

it worked. Things can be so easy and hard at the same time :-(

so, memo to me:

**if a number is returned, make sure you want to print the object it points to (%@), it may be invalid!!**